# @OnDelete(CASCADE) not working on bidirectional mapping (hibernate)

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

I'm using Spring Boot with hibernate 5.0.11.Final

I have the following strange problem. If I define a bidirectional mapping like so

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Device {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "device")
    private Collection<Container> containers = new ArrayList<>();

}


@Data
@Entity
public class Container {

    @ManyToOne
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    private Device device;

}
```

The foreign Key constraint on the container table does not get created with `ON DELETE CASCADE` and therefore deleting a device will not delete its containers.

If I make the mapping one-directional however like so

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Device {
}


@Data
@Entity
public class Container {

    @ManyToOne
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    private Device device;

}
```

the constraint gets generated as expected with `ON DELETE CASCADE` set.

If I set the cascading on the Device side with `@Cascade(CascadeType.DELETE)` and remove the `@OnDelete` the cascading works but on hibernate side without a physical constraint in the database.

Am I doing something wrong? Should I use `@OnDelete` only in one-directional mappings? Is this a bug?

Regards
David

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I encountered a similar problem and after some time of tryouts and debugging I figured out a bit unobvious thing: when you're building a bidirectional relation, the *many* side **silently** rewrites constraints over the *one* side. Thus you should specify *OnDelete* on the other side like this:

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Device {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "device")
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    private Collection<Container> containers = new ArrayList<>();

}


@Data
@Entity
public class Container {

    @ManyToOne
    private Device device;

}
```